# How to get clickable links to functions and classes on VS code for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sorry if the question is not entirely clear. Will add details if unclear.

[image]

`PrintPlugin` is a class from another python file I have imported. I used to get clickable links on this on VS code. Meaning, if I cmd+click on `PrintPlugin` it would go to that class on the source Python file.

My bottom bar used to look like this when it was working.

[image]

Now it looks like this

[image]

The difference is that I was having the `Python 3.9.5 64-bit ('base':conda)` earlier.

Everything else works fine. I am on my virtual environment too. I am not sure what else could be causing this. Will add any details required.

Edit:
I have added some reproducible code. This differs from the original image because the original was work related and I can't post it here. But I'm still running this in the same folder and in the same virtual environment, so it has the same problem (that I cannot cmd+click on `Multiply()` in `process.py` and go to the class on `plugin.py`)

File `process.py`

```
import numpy as np
from plugin import Multiply

a = np.array([[2,3],
            [3,4]])

b = np.array([[5,6],
            [7,8]])

result = Multiply()

print(result.multiply(a,b))
```

File `plugin.py`

```
import numpy as np

class Multiply():
    def __init__(
        self,
        a = np.array([[1,1],
                    [1,1]]),
        b = np.array([[1,1],
                    [1,1]])
    ):
        return

    def multiply(self,a,b):
        c = a @ b
        return c
```

Output when I do `python process.py`

```
>>> [[31 36]
     [43 50]]
```

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux

Comment: @muppi090909 Mac. I have added it on the title.

Comment: Try activating your venv from the command line and then running vscode on that dir.

Comment: @muppi090909 I have tried that. It doesn't work. `project-folder` has a particular venv. I did `code path/to/project-folder` on terminal, and it opens up the folder in a new VS code window. But clickable links still don't work

Comment: can you add steps to reproduce in the question?

Comment: @muppi090909 I have added some code there. Let me know if need any other help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After following the steps I am not able to reproduce the issue